# Building dynamic Aggregation query based on user input in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, aggregation

I want to build aggregation query dynamically based on the user input(may be terms, nested, filters).
input is:

```
{
    "search": [

{

            "aggr": "terms",
            "field": "team",
            "filterFields": []

},


        {
            "aggr": "nested",
            "field": "stage_test.sutname",
            "filterFields": []
        },


        {
            "aggr": "sum",
            "field": "stage_test.stage_run_time"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want each objects in this list as a sub aggregation in order

I am Parsing this list  and inside a for loop am building the query:

```
for (SearchData data : searchInput.getSearch()) {
            System.out.println(data.getField());
            System.out.println(data.getAggr());
            if (termsBuilder != null) {

                 if(data.getAggr().equalsIgnoreCase("sum")){
                    termsBuilder = termsBuilder.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum("sum").field(data.getField()));
                }
                else if(data.getAggr().equalsIgnoreCase("nested")){
                    termsBuilder = termsBuilder.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.nested(data.getAggr()).path(data.getField())
                            .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms(data.getField()).field(data.getField())));
                    System.out.println(XContentHelper.toString(termsBuilder));
                }
            } 
            else {
                if(data.getAggr().equalsIgnoreCase("terms"))
                {
                    if(data.getFilterFields().size() == 0){
                        termsBuilder =  AggregationBuilders.terms(data.getField()).field(data.getField())
                                .size(0);
                    }
                    else{
                        String includeinput[] = new String[data.getFilterFields().size()];
                        includeinput = data.getFilterFields().toArray(includeinput);
                        termsBuilder =  AggregationBuilders.terms(data.getField()).field(data.getField())
                                .include(includeinput).size(0);
                    }

                }


            }
        }
```

I tried to print the query builded:

```
{

  "team" : {

    "terms" : {

      "field" : "team",
      "size" : 0
    },
    "aggregations" : {
      "nested" : {
        "nested" : {
          "path" : "stage_test.sutname"
        },
        "aggregations" : {
          "stage_test.sutname" : {
            "terms" : {
              "field" : "stage_test.sutname"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "sum" : {
        "sum" : {
          "field" : "stage_test.stage_run_time"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As in query the last part (i.e.. sum) I wanted that as sub aggregation but it came out of aggregation

Comment: I am also trying to form the elastic query based on conditions and it's coming without sub aggregation. It would be great if you already have any solutions to your problem statement.